How to change timezone of dt variables in lubridate within loop?
I'm working with time data expressed in seconds since epoch. I have individual Excel files, and want to format time as M-D-Y H:M:S. I've tried to write a loop to create a new dt variable for each file, and then change the extracted times to EST. Reproducible example included below.
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

time1 <- as.vector(c(1721138400, 1721142000, 1721145600, 1721149200, 1721152800, 1721156400, 1721160000, 1721163600))
time2 <- as.vector(c(1721167200, 1721170800, 1721174400, 1721178000, 1721181600, 1721185200, 1721188800, 1721192400))

sample_1 <- as.data.frame(time1)

sample_2 <- as.data.frame(time2) |>
  rename(time1 = time2)

write_xlsx(sample_1, "sample_1.xlsx")
write_xlsx(sample_2, "sample_2.xlsx")

files <- list.files(path = "F:/Documents/mydata", pattern = "sample")

wd <- "F:/Documents/mydata"

for (file in files) {
  the_data <- read_excel(file) |>
    mutate(dt = as_datetime(time1),
           dt_adj = with_tz(dt, tzone = "EST"))

  write_xlsx(the_data, path = paste0(wd, "/", basename(file)))


}

The code will take each Excel file, create new variables, and write a new file, but the times are not expressed in EST, instead they stay as UTC.
However, I am able to create a dt variable in EST while manipulating individual dataframes (below).
sample_2 |>
  mutate(dt = as_datetime(time1),
         dt_adj = with_tz(dt, tzone = "EST"))

The code above returns new columns, but does not change the timezone unless I edit each dataframe individually. Is there a workaround for this, or does each file need to be edited individually?

dt_adj = with_tz(dt, tzone = "EST") |> force_tz("UTC")

Excel doesn't have time zones, as far as I'm aware, and R datetimes are saved in UTC but with a time zone attribute. So when you change the timezone and write to Excel, the only thing that makes it is the original time, not the changed time zone. So you can add a second step to make it a UTC time with the same nominal appearance as your EST time.
For example, we can look under the hood with dput(). This shows that changing the tzone doesn't change the underlying time, so it's not too surprising that exporting to Excel preserves the underlying time instead of the "appearance" of the time. But force_tz() changes the underlying time in UTC to match the nominal time we're seeing, so I expect that will export to Excel how you expect.
data.frame(dt = as.POSIXct(1721167200),
           dt2 = as.POSIXct(1721167200) |> with_tz(tzone = "EST"),
           dt3 = as.POSIXct(1721167200) |> with_tz(tzone = "EST") |> force_tz("UCT")) |>
  dput()

structure(list(
     dt  = structure(1721167200, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
     dt2 = structure(1721167200, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), 
     dt3 = structure(1721149200, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UCT")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))

